# I want to enable two factor sms based authentication with all gmail account

Tags: firebase, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

We have a requirement to enable two-factor authentication with Gmail account. We have integrated Gmail authentication handler with our application. Once the user logins to our application through Gmail using Gmail account credentials,  we want to enable SMS based authentication once again.

I tried with my personal email by enabling two-factor authentication. It is working fine. But when we go all the users, how can we achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It should work fine since that would be automatically handled by Gmail and not Firebase Auth. If it works for you then it should also for other accounts

Comment: Sorry. Below is my clear explanation. We have an application with Gmail integration auth handler. When the external user's logins with their Gmail account to our application, I want those users to have two-factor authentication via SMS. How can I achieve this  functionality

Comment: AFIK, you would need to either use https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth

Comment: Your comment should be part of your question to make it clear. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)